# Getting local machine and all user certificates with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

I can get all certificates in local machine and *current* user stores by doing

```
Get-ChildItem Cert: -Recurse |
    ? { $_ -is [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2] }
```

How do I do the same thing for *all* users on the local machine?
<sub>(I need to find a certain certificate and all I know is a serial number and that it is definitely installed in some store)</sub>

Comment: User certificates are stored in the user's registry hive, so you'd need to either log in as the user or load his hive into the registry and manually [decode the certificate BLOBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381955(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. If those are the only ways to do it, then I think you should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User certificates are stored in the user's registry hive, so you'd need to either log in as the particular user or load his hive into the registry and manually [decode the certificate BLOBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm not aware of other ways to get the certificates of another user.