# Retrieving certificates installed under a different User. Get-ChildItem Cert:\<username>\My

Tags: powershell, certificate

I want the powershell equivalent for retrieving certificates installed under a *different* user.

Does something like this exist?

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\<username>\My
```

More options other just `LocalMachine` or `CurrentUser`. 
This command is executed by a Admin account.

**Update:**

While this does not answer my question, I was able to locate the certifcate on the filesystem. Certs for installed for a local user are located under:

```
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712066/getting-local-machine-and-all-user-certificates-with-powershell

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: BTW, I think those files in Crypto\RSA aren't the user certificates, just their private keys. Certificates in the stores without a private key don't have a corresponding file.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is not possible. User's certificate store is encrypted using user's password. So without the password of the user you cannot access it.

Comment: what if I have the password for a system account?

Comment: "Not possible" is not the same as "not possible unless you have the other user's password". If you have the password, it's possible. We need to know how to do it, though.