# How to get all certificates with powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to get all certificates with powershell. When I set "\$computer\My" as store location below script returns user certificates I think.

When I set "\$computer\root" it returns root certificates. How can I get both user and machine certificates?

```
$computer='localhost';
$ro=[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadOnly"
$lm=[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]"LocalMachine"
$store=new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("\\$computer\My",$lm)
$store.Open($ro)
$certificates=$store.Certificates
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting local machine and all user certificates with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712066/getting-local-machine-and-all-user-certificates-with-powershell)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is a PSDrive `Cert`, which contains `CurrentUser` and `LocalMachine`.

So this get you all certificates:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -Recurse
```

Answer (score 7):

Specifically to get user and localmachine certificates (only):

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | ft

Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ft
```